# An alternate 3D geometry where there is a single origin where parallel lines intersect?

Tags: geometry, 3d, solid-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I'm a programmer trying to get my head around the math I need for a problem and was hoping it has been covered in one branch of mathematics or another.

My model is a continuously expanding space (like the inner volume of an expanding balloon) where shapes behave locally as if they are euclidean but shrink non-uniformly as they are moved toward the origin - imagine an infinite line of wire framed cubes and a camera looking straight down the tunnel they create to the vanishing point at its center, as the camera moves in or out everything measures as it should for euclidean geometry (taking into account lens magnification etc); but then change the rules so that the vanishing point is actually a true point where parallel lines converge (but for a drone camera zooming through the tunnel the point would remain infinitely far away as the drone continued to shrink).

Any papers or places to start on putting this into mathematics (well my bastardized version of mathematics called source code) or at least formulate a coherent description so I can search further on the internet?

**Edit**
To clarify below is a grid to illustrate: the grid cells depicted here have a radial length equal to the average of the inner and outer arc lengths and the origin can be zoomed in on indefinately.

[image: Grid illustrating the geometry]

Comment: Why should this "always receding point" be necessarily considered as the origin ? What prevents you to take instead this point as, say, the point at infinity on the $x$ axis $(1,0,0,\color{red}{0})$ (in homogeneous coordinates, explaining the 4th coord.) ?

Comment: Why should the vanishing point in the drones view by considered as the origin? Because that is the way I want the model space to behave as I calculate the mechanics effecting the objects within.

Comment: As you are asking for ideas, the overall idea I had is to "map" the mathematical tools you have used (be it based on a continuous or discrete version of differential equations, or things like that) from the origin to the point at infinity. It was just an idea alike what is done by physicists in fluid dynamics when they us "conformal mapping".